# Changing NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName animated for attributeText property

Tags: uilabel, nsattributedstring, core-text

I'm just trying to implement changing the `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` for particular `NSRange` of my string layouting in `UILabel`. The problem is I want to make it using some simple animation. Is there a way to change the `attributedText` property using any animation or it is required to use hardCoreText to make it done?